# Python and openCV theft detection program

Tags: python, opencv

My group was tasked to create a theft detection program using OpenCV and python

Currently facing a problem where my program is able to open windows but would crash after a few seconds of launching the program returning these error codes but I am not knowledgeable enough in python and openCV to fix this:

```
cv2.rectangle(thresh,(x,y),(x+y+w+h),(0,255,255),2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
Overload resolution failed:
- Can't parse 'pt2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
- Can't parse 'pt2'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
- Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
- Can't parse 'rec'. Expected sequence length 4, got 2
```

Here is my complete code for reference, hope I can get some lead or guide on how to resolve this issue and what I should look out for:

```
import cv2
import numpy

# Font that will be used
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#----------------
# Put all output into one window method
def combineWindow(scale,imgArray,labs=[]):
    sizeW = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    sizeH = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range (0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (sizeW, sizeH), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y]= cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype="uint8")
        hor = [imageBlank]*rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = numpy.hstack(imgArray[x])
            hor_con[x] = numpy.concatenate(imgArray[x])
        ver = numpy.vstack(hor)
        ver_con = numpy.concatenate(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (sizeW, sizeH), None, scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor = numpy.hstack(imgArray)
        hor_con = numpy.concatenate(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    if len(labs) != 0:
        eachImgWidth = int(ver.shape[1]/cols)
        eachImgHeight = int(ver.shape[0]/rows)
        print(eachImgHeight)
        for d in range(0, rows):
            for c in range (0,cols):
                cv2.rectangle(ver,(c*eachImgWidth,eachImgHeight*d),(c*eachImgWidth+len(labs[d][c])*13+27,30+eachImgHeight*d),(255,255,255),cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(ver,labs[d][c],(eachImgWidth*c+10,eachImgHeight*d+20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.7,(255,0,255),2)
    return ver

#------------------
# Frame checker method
def checkFrame(referenceFrame, frame):
    # Convert the current frame to grayscale
    gray_frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
    blur_frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame,(15,15), 0)
        
    # Calculate difference between the reference frame and the post processed current frame
    difference=cv2.absdiff(blur_frame, referenceFrameBlur)    
        
    # Get the threshold of the difference between the two frames
    _,thresh=cv2.threshold(difference, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        
    # Identify the contour in the threshold
    contours,_=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Applies bounding boxes to each valid contours
    for contour in contours:
        # Gets the bounding box coordinates of each contour
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            
        # Ignores the contour if it has an area less than 1200
        if cv2.contourArea(contour)>1200:
            # Yellow bounding box around the contour
            cv2.rectangle(thresh,(x,y),(x+y+w+h),(0,255,255),2)
            # Red alert indicating there is a motion in the frame
            cv2.putText(thresh,"Intruder alert",(50,200),font,2,(0,0,255),2)
            
    return thresh, difference


#------------------
# Main method

#capture video feed 
# Change the number to select the camera you would like to use as I have multiple cameras
capture=cv2.VideoCapture(1,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,360)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,480)

ret,frame=capture.read()

referenceFrame=frame
referenceFrameGray=None
referenceFrameBlur=None
running=True

while True:
    
    # Comparison of frames with the selected reference frame
    ret,frame=capture.read()
        
    # Convert the selected frame to grayscale
    referenceFrameGray=cv2.cvtColor(referenceFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
    # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
    referenceFrameBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(referenceFrameGray,(15,15), 0)
            
    thresh, difference=checkFrame(referenceFrame,frame)
            
    cv2.putText(referenceFrame,"Reference frame",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame,"Live feed",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(difference,"Frame difference",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(thresh,"Binary difference",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
            
    combinedOutput=combineWindow(0.8,([referenceFrame,frame], [difference,thresh]))
    cv2.imshow("Theft Alert", combinedOutput)
            
    #-----Key Functions-----      
    # Needs to be set to 1 to allow the feed to keep going  
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
            
    # Sets the reference frame
    if key==ord('0'):
        refrenceFrame=frame
                
        # Convert the selected frame to grayscale
        referenceFrameGray=cv2.cvtColor(referenceFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                
        # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
        referenceFrameBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(referenceFrameGray,(15,15), 0)
            
    if key==ord('q') or key==ord('Q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input for cv2.recangle was wrong. Try:

```py
cv2.rectangle(thresh,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
```

In the 3rd input, you need to give end points correctly.

Complete code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy

# Font that will be used
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

#----------------
# Put all output into one window method
def combineWindow(scale,imgArray,labs=[]):
    sizeW = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    sizeH = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    rows = len(imgArray)
    cols = len(imgArray[0])
    rowsAvailable = isinstance(imgArray[0], list)
    width = imgArray[0][0].shape[1]
    height = imgArray[0][0].shape[0]
    if rowsAvailable:
        for x in range (0, rows):
            for y in range(0, cols):
                imgArray[x][y] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x][y], (sizeW, sizeH), None, scale, scale)
                if len(imgArray[x][y].shape) == 2: imgArray[x][y]= cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x][y], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        imageBlank = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype="uint8")
        hor = [imageBlank]*rows
        hor_con = [imageBlank]*rows
        for x in range(0, rows):
            hor[x] = numpy.hstack(imgArray[x])
            hor_con[x] = numpy.concatenate(imgArray[x])
        ver = numpy.vstack(hor)
        ver_con = numpy.concatenate(hor)
    else:
        for x in range(0, rows):
            imgArray[x] = cv2.resize(imgArray[x], (sizeW, sizeH), None, scale, scale)
            if len(imgArray[x].shape) == 2: imgArray[x] = cv2.cvtColor(imgArray[x], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        hor = numpy.hstack(imgArray)
        hor_con = numpy.concatenate(imgArray)
        ver = hor
    if len(labs) != 0:
        eachImgWidth = int(ver.shape[1]/cols)
        eachImgHeight = int(ver.shape[0]/rows)
        print(eachImgHeight)
        for d in range(0, rows):
            for c in range (0,cols):
                cv2.rectangle(ver,(c*eachImgWidth,eachImgHeight*d),(c*eachImgWidth+len(labs[d][c])*13+27,30+eachImgHeight*d),(255,255,255),cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(ver,labs[d][c],(eachImgWidth*c+10,eachImgHeight*d+20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.7,(255,0,255),2)
    return ver

#------------------
# Frame checker method
def checkFrame(referenceFrame, frame):
    # Convert the current frame to grayscale
    gray_frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
    blur_frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_frame,(15,15), 0)
        
    # Calculate difference between the reference frame and the post processed current frame
    difference=cv2.absdiff(blur_frame, referenceFrameBlur)    
        
    # Get the threshold of the difference between the two frames
    _,thresh=cv2.threshold(difference, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        
    # Identify the contour in the threshold
    contours,_=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Applies bounding boxes to each valid contours
    for contour in contours:
        # Gets the bounding box coordinates of each contour
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            
        # Ignores the contour if it has an area less than 1200
        if cv2.contourArea(contour)>1200:
            # Yellow bounding box around the contour
            cv2.rectangle(thresh,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)
            # Red alert indicating there is a motion in the frame
            cv2.putText(thresh,"Intruder alert",(50,200),font,2,(0,0,255),2)
            
    return thresh, difference


#------------------
# Main method

#capture video feed 
# Change the number to select the camera you would like to use as I have multiple cameras
capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,360)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,480)

ret,frame=capture.read()

referenceFrame=frame
referenceFrameGray=None
referenceFrameBlur=None
running=True

while True:
    
    # Comparison of frames with the selected reference frame
    ret,frame=capture.read()
        
    # Convert the selected frame to grayscale
    referenceFrameGray=cv2.cvtColor(referenceFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
    # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
    referenceFrameBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(referenceFrameGray,(15,15), 0)
            
    thresh, difference=checkFrame(referenceFrame,frame)
            
    cv2.putText(referenceFrame,"Reference frame",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame,"Live feed",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(difference,"Frame difference",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.putText(thresh,"Binary difference",(0,50),font,1,(0,255,0), 2)
            
    combinedOutput=combineWindow(0.8,([referenceFrame,frame], [difference,thresh]))
    cv2.imshow("Theft Alert", combinedOutput)
            
    #-----Key Functions-----      
    # Needs to be set to 1 to allow the feed to keep going  
    key=cv2.waitKey(1)
            
    # Sets the reference frame
    if key==ord('0'):
        refrenceFrame=frame
                
        # Convert the selected frame to grayscale
        referenceFrameGray=cv2.cvtColor(referenceFrame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                
        # Applying smoothing to reduce noise
        referenceFrameBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(referenceFrameGray,(15,15), 0)
            
    if key==ord('q') or key==ord('Q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This fixed the problem in my code. Thank you so much!